# how to add title of woocommerce dimension attributes?

Tags: php, wordpress

how to show title of dimensions of dimension attribute?

now it shows like this:

dimensions: 13 × 13 × 34 cm

I want to show like this:

dimensions: 13 Length × 13 Width  × 34 Height cm

```
<table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
    <?php foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute_key => $product_attribute ) : ?>
        <?php
        $attribute_name = str_replace( 'attribute_pa_', '', $product_attribute_key );
        $thumb_id       = get_option( 'woodmart_pa_' . $attribute_name . '_thumbnail' );
        $image_size     = apply_filters( 'woodmart_product_attributes_table_image_size', 'thumbnail' );
        ?>

        <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
            <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label">
                <?php if ( ! empty( $thumb_id ) ) : ?>
                    <?php if ( woodmart_is_svg( wp_get_attachment_image_url( $thumb_id ) ) ) : ?>
                        <?php echo woodmart_get_svg_html( $thumb_id, $image_size, array( 'class' => 'wd-attr-img' ) ); //phpcs:ignore. ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $thumb_id, $image_size, false, array( 'class' => 'wd-attr-img' ) ); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <span>
                    <?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['label'] ); ?>
                </span>
            </th>
            <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value">
                <?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['value'] ); ?>
                
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Is your attribute created as one attribute "Dimensions" ? Or are each dimensional attribute (width, height, length) created separatly? The question is whether this value `13 × 13 × 34 cm` is the value of the attribute "dimension", or if each value `13` , `13` , `34` is linked to its own attribute `width` , `length`, `height` ? There is a huge difference between having one attribute "dimensions" and having 3 separate attributes "width", "length", "height".